# Need for a comma here?

Tags: punctuation

I found the following sentence in a preposition-quiz.

**"Working parents often find it difficult to keep children who are at home entertained during the summer months.**

I think it is a "***Defining relative clause***" that gives essential information with **"who are at home"**. So there is no need for a comma. But i am unsure - can you confirm ?

Comment: Yes, it's an essential/restrictive relative clause, so no comma. It is essential to know which children.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if original sentence needs a comma or not, but I would consider revising for readability.

**"During the summer months, working parents often find it difficult to keep children entertained while they are home."**

Comment: Your answer does not refer to the question/issue of "defining relative clauses" and "puntuation".

Comment: Maybe not, but the sole purpose of punctuation is to provide clarity and readability in text.  There is more to a clear and readable sentence than just punctuation.

Comment: In cases of "essential clauses", the Cambridge Dictionary does not seems to share that opinion with you.

Answer (score -1):

The adjectival phrase,"who are at home', should be set off by commas. This phrase defines the noun, "children", just as any adjective modifies any noun.

Comment: Sorry, but you've got it backwards.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/relative-clauses/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the reasons we ask people to support their answers with comments is that quite frequently, when looking for such support, we learn that our original understanding was incorrect.